# control div tags along with Umbraco

Tags: html, css, umbraco

I am struggling to place my div tags together with the Umbraco grid. This is how it should look like:

[image: This is how it should look like]

I can achieve that with setting `<br>` tags in the code, but that is of course not a good practice:

```
<div class="background-image" @Html.Raw(topImageStyling)></div>
    <div class="max-container">
        <div class="fade"></div>

        <header>
            <div class="max-container">
                <div class="logo-container">
                    <a href="@homePage.Url">
                        <!-- <img src="/img/logo-white.svg" data-svg-fallback="/img/logo-white.png" alt="@logoAltText" class="img-responsive logo" /> -->
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>


    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Ebook")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("Grid")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I remove the `<br>` tags the page is looking like this:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how I could solve that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Umbraco, it's the (Bootstrap) styling that's to blame. Maybe you can check getbootstrap.com for tips or even give this question a "bootstrap" tag. Otherwise I agree with Randy, you should be able to set min-height on your header to avoid OR remove the container-fluid div entirely?

Comment: Can you post CSS styles or any of the markup from your EBook macro? This looks like either an issue with positioning or an overflow issue in CSS. If the former, you'll probably need the `min-height` changes, but if it's floated you can generally fix it with a `clearfix` class or a simple `overflow: auto;` CSS attribute on the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lot of `<br>` tags is **never** a good practice.

You can add `margin` or `padding` via CSS.

In this case, it seems like you have a form that is positioned absolute. Because of that, your page doesn't track its dimensions in the container.

You probably want to set the minimum height of the container in your CSS.

For example, you can add a style tag. Please, don't use the actual style tag though, and edit your CSS file:

CSS

```
.myHeader {
    min-height:500px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="container-fluid" class="myHeader">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Ebook")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("Grid")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```